# CSS Icons: Cannot remove top and bottom padding (font awesome)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-3.2

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/schmudde/VeA6B/

I cannot remove the top and bottom padding on either side of a font awesome icon:

```
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
    line-height: 40%;
}
i {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background-color: red;
}

<span><i class="icon-check icon-3x"></i></span>
```

I have attempted specific line-heights and inheriting line-heights. There is something fundamental here I am clearly not understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `line-height` on the span won't help you much as the icon is added to the pseudo class `:before` on the `<i />` tag. This pseudo class will create a somewhat hidden element, if you can call it that.

So if you want to override the css:

```
.icon-check:before { font-size: 2rem; }
```

Removing the padding of the icon can be tricky. Maybe if you set the `span` to `display: inline-block` you can use `height`, `width` in combination with `overflow: hidden`.

```
span {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 45px;
}
i.icon-check:before {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/CL9dy/)

Comment: Brilliant. I couldn't find many posts on this particular issue and it was driving me crazy. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 11):

Use `span { line-height: 100%; }` so it would fill the block.

Answer (score 0):

You set borders in `span`, and line inheriting line-heights in `i`, that's the problem.

just add borders to `i` :

```
span {
   line-height: 40%;
     }
i {
   border: 1px solid red;
   border: 1px solid green;
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   line-height: inherit;
   vertical-align: baseline;
   background-color: red;
   }

   <span><i class="icon-check icon-3x"></i></span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VeA6B/3/)